# How to add an unspecified amount of variables together?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to add in python 3.5.2 but I have an unspecified amount of variables. I have to use very basic functions; I can't use `list`. I can't figure out how I'm supposed to add each new variable together without a `list`. When I run the code it adds the last entered `price1` which is `-1`. I need to use the `-1` to tell the program to total all the variables.

```
count = 0

while (True):

     price1 = int( input("Enter the price of item, or enter -1 to get total: "))

     count += 1

     if (price1 ==-1):
         subtotal = (price1 + ) #this is where I"m having trouble
                                #at least I think this is the problem
         tax = (subtotal*0.05)
         total = (subtotal + tax)

         print("Subtotal: .  .  . . . ", subtotal)
         print("Tax: . .  . . . . . . ", tax)
         print("Total: . . . . . . . .", total)

         break
```

Comment: Your question is unclear , what exact output you are expecting ?

Comment: I'm trying to get the subtotal. I figured If i can get that I cant figure out the total wit the tax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it. Looking at your code, what I would suggest you do is create a `subtotal` variable just outside of your loop and initialize it to `0`. Furthermore, you are not using `count` for anything, so get rid of that.

When you get your `price` input, check it right after for the `-1` condition. If you have a `-1` value, then proceed with your *math*, otherwise your `else` will start running the `subtotal` with the `subtotal += price`.

So, you should have something like:

```
subtotal = 0
while (True):

     price = int( input("Enter the price of item, or enter -1 to get total: "))

     if price == -1:
         tax = subtotal*0.05
         total = subtotal + tax

         print("Subtotal: .  .  . . . ", subtotal)
         print("Tax: . .  . . . . . . ", tax)
         print("Total: . . . . . . . .", total)

         break
     else:
         subtotal += price
```

Comment: How is the count not being used? I thought you need some kind of count so that way it doesn't run forever.

Comment: @John You are never using your `count` to check it against any values to know if you should even break your `while`. You are setting a `break`inside your `if price == -1` condition which is what will *break* out of your loop

Comment: Thank you. I cant believe I was that close to it. I really am kicking myself for it now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Keep another variable around and sum than up, also, `count` isn't used for anything so no real reason to keep it around.

For example, initialize a `price` name to `0`:

```
price = 0
```

then, check if the value is `-1` and, if not, simply increment (`+=`) the `price` variable with the value obtained for `price1`:

```
if price1 == -1:
    subtotal = price 
    tax =  subtotal*0.05
    total = subtotal + tax

    print("Subtotal: .  .  . . . ", subtotal)
    print("Tax: . .  . . . . . . ", tax)
    print("Total: . . . . . . . .", total)

    break
else:
    price += price1
```

Comment: You can get rid off those parentheses after the `if` statement

Comment: I need to use the while loop though

Comment: Indeed I can, missed those for some reason. Thanks for pointing it out @Dex'ter.

Comment: @John you *are* using a while loop. I just added the `else` clause and made `subtotal = price`.

Comment: @John add the above snippet in the while, below the line `price1 = int(input("Enter the price of item, or enter -1 to get total: "))`

Comment: might want to add the `count` before the `price += price` or else the `-1` is going to increment the counter, guessing OP is going to use the `count` variable somewhere.

Comment: @tesseract I guess? That's why I opted to not include it, I agree that it should be incremented inside the `else` clause but only if he actually uses it.

Comment: @Jim Fasarakis-Hilliard and everyone else thank you for your help!